# Autoscroll in nestedScrollView not working

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I have a `ScrollView`, placed inside of a `nestedScrollview` with drag and drop. But when I'm trying to use drag and drop to a last element of a list and trying to move it on top of it (first element is not visible), my scroll view not scrolling automatically.

But if I will remove `NestedScrollView` and leave only `ScrollView`, auto-scroll works. How to fix this?

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:scrollbars="none">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_medium_32dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin_general_16dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin_general_16dp"
                    android:text="@string/favorite_stores_title"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/smokyblack"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_big" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_general_16dp"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin_general_16dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin_general_16dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_medium_32dp"
                    android:text="@string/favorite_stores_subtitle"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/grullo"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_15sp" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_small_1dp"
                    android:background="@color/isabelline" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/multiple_stores_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:overScrollMode="never"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: You have done a mistake. Height of nestedscrollview should be **match_parent** and its child view _LinearLayout_ height should `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent`

Comment: Where is your java code of move?